# How to binding friendlist as longlistselector in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, longlistselector

I making an app chat in windows phone, I have a class name GetFriendResponse as

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RAMACHAT.Model
{

    public class FriendInfo
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public int statusCode { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public _user data { get; set; }

    }
    public class GetFriendResponse
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public int statusCode { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string _id { get; set; }

        public List<_user> data { get; set; }
    }
```

and class _user as

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RAMACHAT.Model
{
    public class _user
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string avatar { get; set; }
        public bool isOnline { get; set; }
        public bool isFollow { get; set; }

    }
}



    }
```

now I want make frendslist as longlistselector when sever response user frendslist

```
 string result = await App.client.getAllFriends();
            string resultHistory = await App.client.getChatHistory();
            resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetFriendResponse>(result);
            var resultHistoryObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HistoryResponse>(resultHistory);

            List<AlphaKeyGroup.AlphaKeyGroup1<_user>> DataSource = AlphaKeyGroup.AlphaKeyGroup1<_user>.CreateGroups(resultObject.data,
                           System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
                           (_user s) => { return s.username; }, true);
            friendList.ItemsSource = DataSource;
```

but it not work , anyone have an idea to fix it,thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

It may be issue of your XAML page binding as you have not shared the design code blocks.
Better you refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx) MSDN page for longlistselector binding.